# Как можно увеличить скорость программы с перестановками?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ввожу с экрана числа N,M,O которые больше и равны нуля
N показывает сколько раз будет использоваться символ '()'. М показывает сколько раз будет использоваться '[]'. O показывает сколько раз будет использоваться '{}'. Нужно найти все перестановки символов.

```
def permut(arr):
    if len(arr) == 0:
        return [arr]
    res = []
    for i, j in enumerate(arr):
        res += [j+k for k in permut(arr[:i]+arr[i+1:])]
    return res



def main():
    N = int(input())
    M = int(input())
    O = int(input())

    array = []
    if N >= 0 and M >= 0 and O >= 0:
        array.append('()' * N)
        array.append('[]' * M)
        array.append('{}' * O)
    simbols = (''.join(map(str, array)))
    mat = list(set(permut(simbols)))
    print('\n'.join(mat))

main()
```

Comment: Но приведены же пары символов

Comment: @Khimer, ваша программа работает. Что вы ещё от неё хотите?

Comment: хочу увеличить скорость, из-за того что я отправляю все элементы массива на другой массив, для больших чисел программа работает слишком долго. Хотел бы узнать как лучше оптимизировать

Comment: Но вы же понимаете что число перестановок огромно?

Comment: да, понимаю, вот и обращаюсь из-за этого

Comment: хотел бы еще узнать, не используя массивы,  каким еще способом можно решить эту задачу ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если считать, что заданы одиночные символы в указанном количестве, то количество перестановок будет

```
 (n + m+o)!/(n!*m!*o!)
```

Если символы из пар разбиваются, то

```
 (2*n + 2*m + 2* o)!/((n!)^2*(m!)^2*(o!)^2)
```

Если нужны сами перестановки (что сомнительно уже при не очень больших параметрах), то стоит нужно использовать  алгоритм next_permutation ([код с сайта nayuki](https://www.nayuki.io/page/next-lexicographical-permutation-algorithm)), не требующий дополнительной памяти. К сожалению, `itertool.permutations` не учитывает одинаковость элементов, и будет генерировать повторы.

```
def next_permutation(arr):
    # Find non-increasing suffix
    i = len(arr) - 1
    while i > 0 and arr[i - 1] >= arr[i]:
        i -= 1
    if i <= 0:
        return False
    
    # Find successor to pivot
    j = len(arr) - 1
    while arr[j] <= arr[i - 1]:
        j -= 1
    arr[i - 1], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i - 1]


    # Reverse suffix
    arr[i : ] = arr[len(arr) - 1 : i - 1 : -1]
    return True
```

Использование:

```
a = sorted(list('[[(')) #начальная перестановка должна быть лексически наименьшей 
print(''.join(a))
while next_permutation(a):
    print(''.join(a))
```

или прямо на строке:

```
a = sorted('[[(')
print(a)
while next_permutation(a):
    print(a)


([[
[([
[[(
```

Comment: Каждый символ из пары должен использоваться по одиночку

Comment: @Khimer А где это описано в задаче? Может, ещё и правильная скобочная последовательность должна образовываться?

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Я посчитал пары неразрывными ради факта того, что можно посчитать а не генерировать. Надеюсь на уточнение условия.

Comment: По задаче даны пары символов, но использовать мы должны каждый символ из пары. Понимаю, что размеры например для четырех пар уже огромны, но тестируют до 7 пар, а там уже 14 символов. Для 14 символов у меня код проводит слишком много операции, даже памяти не хватает, вот и хотел узнать каким образом решить это с меньшим количеством операции

Comment: Какой результат должен быть для 2,1,1?

Comment: ну там должно быть 8! строк

Comment: Откуда вы это взяли - из своего кода? Это неверно. Одинаковые перестановки считаются дважды. Смотрите вторую формулу в ответе

Comment: а не ,извиняюсь. Неправильно прочитал условие задачи, там оказывается повторяющиеся строки не нужно выводить.

Comment: изменил код, можете посмотреть, как можно изменить код так, чтобы не использовалась просто так память

Comment: Покажите точное условие.

Comment: Немогу понять как попусту не тратить память. Спрошу точнее, вот в строке `mat = list(set(permut(simbols)))` я вызвал `permut(simbols)` сохранится ли этот массив в памяти? Ну и вот пример (2, 0, 4) у меня уже памяти не хватает это выполнить.

Comment: Я классический код привёл

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не тратить память на хранение перестановок надо использовать генератор который будет отдавать перестановку в работу как только она готова. Внизу рекурсивный генератор, порождающий каждую перестановку один раз:

```
def permutations(seq):
    lst = list(seq)

    def gen(i):
        if i == len(seq):
            yield tuple(lst)
        else:
            used = set()
            for j in range(i, len(seq)):
                if lst[j] not in used:
                    used.add(lst[j])
                    lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]
                    yield from gen(i + 1)
                    lst[i], lst[j] = lst[j], lst[i]

    return gen(0)


def main():
    n = int(input())
    m = int(input())
    o = int(input())

    symbols = '()' * n + '[]' * m + '{}' * o
    for p in permutations(symbols):
        print(''.join(p))
    

main()
```

> ```
> $ echo -e "0\n0\n2" | python permutations.py
> {}{}
> {}}{
> {{}}
> }{{}
> }{}{
> }}{{
>
> $ time echo -e "2\n2\n2" | python permutations.py | wc -l
> 7484400
>
> real  0m22.419s
> user  0m22.544s
> sys   0m0.088s
> ```